# "Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create()" even though enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, sockets

I have a weird PHP problem. I am running PHP 5 on IIS in Windows 7. When I make a call to socket_create in my PHP file, like so:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, getprotobyname('udp'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() ...
```

I have tried everything, ranging from enabling `extension=php_sockets.dll` in php.ini, php.ini-development and php.ini-production to restarting IIS and rebooting my computer.

However, I keep getting the same error and am confused. So far I have found no solution on the internet, as I have tried everything.

Also worth of mentioning. The dll is clearly installed in one of the subfolders.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` return sockets enabled?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think it's enabled as I only see: Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp

Comment: What php.ini file is loaded? See `Loaded Configuration File` in phpinfo().

Comment: C:\php\php.ini is being loaded as it states, but in there 'extension=php_sockets.dll' is uncommented

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with caching, but I don't know how to clear PHP's cache.

Comment: Have you restarted webserver when you have changed php.ini settings?

Comment: Yes, I did. See my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type in the following command from your command line:

```
php --ini
```

That will tell you which php.ini file is being loaded. I suspect you are running websockets from the command line, and your php is initializing a different config file when in CLI mode.

Comment: Thank you! While running the php --ini command, I noticed that it was referring to an unfound "C:\php\php_sockets.dll". The extension was installed, but was placed in the wrong directory. It works now ...