# how do i enable sockets on lighttpd server

Tags: php, sockets, lighttpd

[myphpinfopage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0E6i.png)i have a `lighttpd` server on my embedded system and its running and can show my php code but i cant use sockets because i get an error saying that says

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function `socket_create()`;
```

I recently tried the `PHP` code on my PC which is running an `apache server` and it works fine but not on my embedded system. I'm using `lighttpd` on my embedded system because its light.

I'm already enable `extension=php_sockets.dll` in my `php.ini` file but the problem still the same and i can't see that --enable-sockets in my `phpinfo` configure command.

Does someone have an idea what did i do wrong?

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of other questions with **exactly** the same text.  Before posting, please search stackoverflow for similar questions (and preferably also search the internet using your favorite search engine).

["Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create()" even though enabled in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659654/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-socket-create-even-though-enabled-in)

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137823/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-socket-create)

[phpwebsocket - Undefined Function socket_create() - Have php_sockets enabled on Windows/WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564100/phpwebsocket-undefined-function-socket-create-have-php-sockets-enabled-on)

[Error with PHP Websocket and Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705630/error-with-php-websocket-and-wamp-server)